Chrome Extension Content Scripts Not Working on Zendesk
I've developed a Chrome extension designed to interact with content on different websites.
It’s supposed to expand text shortcuts into predefined phrases when typed into text areas or input fields.
However, it’s not working on Zendesk, though it works on other sites. The extension uses content scripts to listen for input events and uses chrome.storage to manage shortcuts. Zendesk seems to ignore the scripts completely
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "psychic-guacamole ",
  "version": "1.2",
  "description": "Text Expander replacement",
  "permissions": [
    "storage", 
    "activeTab", 
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*.zendesk.com/*"
  ],
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16":"icons/uwu16.png",
    "128": "icons/uwu.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_popup_width": 700,  
    "default_popup_height": 1000,
    "default_icon": {
      "16":"icons/uwu16.png",
      "128": "icons/uwu.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "commands": {
    "expand_shortcut": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E"
      },
      "description": "Trigger text expansion"
    }
  }
}

function handleExpansion(node) {
  console.log("Adding event listener to node", node); // Debug: log node to which listener is added
    node.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        const text = node.innerHTML;
        console.log("Input event triggered. Current text:", text); 

      chrome.storage.sync.get('shortcuts', function(data) {
          const shortcuts = data.shortcuts || {};
          console.log("Shortcuts loaded:", shortcuts);
          Object.keys(shortcuts).forEach((shortcut) => {
              if (text.includes(shortcut)) {  // Check if the current text includes the shortcut
                  let expandedText = shortcuts[shortcut];
                  const placeholders = expandedText.match(/\{[^}]+\}/g);
                  console.log("Processing shortcut:", shortcut, "with placeholders:", placeholders);

                  if (placeholders) {
                      injectModal(placeholders, (values) => {
                        console.log("Placeholder values provided:", values);
                          placeholders.forEach((placeholder) => {
                              expandedText = expandedText.replace(new RegExp(`\\${placeholder}`, 'g'), values[placeholder]);
                              console.log("Text after replacement:", expandedText);
                          });
                          updateElementText(node, text, shortcut, expandedText);
                      });
                  } else {
                      updateElementText(node, text, shortcut, expandedText);
                  }
              }
          });
      });
  });
}


function updateElementText(element, originalText, shortcut, newText) {
  if (element.tagName === "TEXTAREA" || element.tagName === "INPUT" || element.tagName === ".ck-editor__editable") {
    element.value = originalText.replace(shortcut, newText);
  } else if (element.isContentEditable) {
    element.innerHTML = originalText.replace(shortcut, newText);
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  console.log("Mutation observed:", mutationsList); // Debug: log all mutations observed
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
              console.log("New node added:", node); // Debug: log each new node added
              if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.isContentEditable) {
                  handleExpansion(node);
              }
          });
      }
  }
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]').forEach(handleExpansion);

Where am I going wrong here?

Use devtools to inspect the site: it probably puts the inputs inside an iframe or inside shadow DOM.
